# Repeated deployments in Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I am trying to do repeated deployments in Powershell, so each time I want to delete the current site collection, so I execute this every time:

```
remove-spsite http://server 
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "BLANKINTERNET"
New-SPSite -Url "http://server" -OwnerAlias "domain\administrator" -Template $template
```

But when the site is created, it displays it in a weird way, like below:

[image]

Comment: Is this occurs for a specific template or all templates ?

Comment: I didn't try, I am only interested in creating publishing site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `Publishing Template` as

```
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "BLANKINTERNET#0"
```

This template creates a site for publishing Web pages on a schedule, with workflow features enabled. By default, only Publishing subsites can be created under this site. A Document and Picture Library are included for storing Web publishing assets.

See also [sharepoint-2013-site-templates-codes-for-powershell](http://www.funwithsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-site-templates-codes-for-powershell/)

Comment: I tried this one, didn't work. If you try it on your side, you will end up with same results as me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the template names are the same for SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013, that are a part of SharePoint 2013 for compatibility reasons. So creating a new sp-site, SharePoint might pick up elements from both the 14 and 15 hive folders (2010 and 2013).

Try to specify the [CompatibilityLevel](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607937.aspx) parameter when using the `New-SPSite` cmdlt.

Your code should look like this:

```
Remove-SPSite http://server 
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "BLANKINTERNET#0"
New-SPSite -Url "http://server" -OwnerAlias "domain\administrator" -Template $template -CompatibilityLevel 15
```